# Java Object assignment when passing to a method

Tags: java, pointers, object, methods

I have the following

```
class Test{

    public Inner x;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Test t = new Test();
        t.bar(t.x);

    }

    public Test(){
        x = new Inner();
        System.out.println("X = "+x.val);
    }

    public void bar(Inner a){
        x.val = 2;
        System.out.println("a = "+a.val);
        a = new Inner(5);
        System.out.println("a = "+a.val);
        System.out.println("X = "+this.x.val);
    }

    class Inner{
        public int val;
        public Inner(){val=0;}
        public Inner(int i){val=i;}
    }
}
```

I am concerned why the program tells me that my class's inner object and passed-in object are the same, but when I change the passed object to a new one, they are suddenly not the same. I thought java passed by pointers, and thus changing the pointer location of "a" in my bar method would likewise change the pointer location of "x", which was passed in.

Comment: Passing by pointers is different from passing by reference. Changing a pointer to point somewhere else does not change other pointers to also point there.

Comment: So how can I achieve the desired effect in this program? Which is passing in an object variable and changing it inside the method?

Comment: You can't pass arguments by reference in Java. If you want to change `x` from within `bar()`, you can just set `x = new Inner(5);`. If that's not an option, you'll have to use a mutable wrapper class.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying. Can you expound on how to use a mutable wrapper class? Or is there a good web resource that explains it well?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change by "a", to change the "x" it?  Keyword "new" will open up a new memory, so the function "bar" inside your "x" and "a" is a pointer to a different memory, you modify the "a" will not change "x". You can try to modify the "bar" as follows:

```
 public void bar(Inner a){
    x.val = 2;
    System.out.println("a = "+a.val);
    //a = new Inner(5);
    a.val = 5;
    System.out.println("a = "+a.val);
    System.out.println("X = "+this.x.val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a totally new object when you do `a = new Inner(5);`

Answer (score 0):

In Java, it is always 'pass by value' and not pass by reference. When you pass `t.x` to your bar method, copy of memory address is created and it is passed to method. Suppose you change `a = null` in your bar method, this will not make your `t.x` to null as only `a` reference variable is set to null in your method.

```
a = new Inner(5);
```

This line reassigning your reference variable to new memory location which is different from `t.x`. Hence any change to this memory location will not any impact to `t.x`.